# C# Вывод данных sqlite в datagridview без datasource

Tags: c#, sqlite

Подскажите, как вывести данные из sqlite в datagridview таким образом, чтобы привязать "DATE" и "FULLNAME" к конкретным столбцам datagridview. Вариант с datasource не устраивает, так как столбец "message" надо преобразовать в base64.

```
string sql = "Select DATE, FULLNAME FROM MESSAGE ";
var conn = new SQLiteConnection("Data Source=" + filename + ";Version=3;");
conn.Open();
DataSet ds = new DataSet();
var da = new SQLiteDataAdapter(sql, conn);
da.Fill(ds);
dataGridView1.DataSource = ds.Tables[0].DefaultView;
```

Comment: Проблема не ясна. В `DataGrid` должно быть всего 2 столбца из 3 или что?

Comment: С DataSource DataGrid формируется автоматически. А мне надо чтобы  данные отправились в массив, а потом попали в необходимые мне столбцы.

Comment: Т.е. в `DataGrid` будут еще другие столбцы не связанные с этим запросом?

Comment: нет, эти же столбцы, но прописанные вручную. до поступления в datagridview я планирую один столбец преобразовать

Comment: Так и преобразовывайте, в чем проблема?

Answer (score 1):

Попробуйте преобразование данных этого столбца "message" выполнять в событии `.GetFormatting()`

Comment: Стоит писать ответы более подробно.